# Error Configuring Zend Server

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, zend-server-ce

I am trying to configure Zend Server CE based on the instructions in the book "Pro Zend Framework Techniques - Build a Full CMS Project".

The book has me do the following:

Alter httpd.conf from:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/rlms/public"

<Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\rlms">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also changed in application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

to:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
```

Is there something wrong with my backslashes and/or forward slashes? Upon going to http://localhost and http://localhost/rlms/public, I receive the following stack trace:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:242 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(358): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3 C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\rlms\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 242

...any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it turns out that I needed to add:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
```

to application.ini, before I was modifying the controllers path